# How can you share someone else's post with the Facebook Graph API using Python?

Tags: python, facebook, api

I want to share posts from pages I do not have API access to. I just want to use the links of these posts to literally 'share' the post as if I 'shared' it manually in Facebook.

The documentation from what I've found on this is sparse.
The code below posts the link as a text post. I don't know if maybe there is another option to input something other than 'message'.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='EAEAEAEAEAEAEAEAEEAEAE___FAKE_ACCESS_TOKEN____AEAEAEAEAEAEAEAEEA', version='3.1')
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="https://www.facebook.com/tacobell/videos/252550596159857")
```

(The Facebook Graph API allows you to post to a Facebook page you control with your software, just to be super clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. If you do everything the same as the OP but change 'message' to link and paste the link of the Facebook post it is published to the page just as if it was 'shared' on Facebook.

```
graph.put_object("me", "feed", link="https://www.facebook.com/tacobell/videos/252550596159857")
```